# Load html form on the basis of Dropdown value?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating one form in html using table. Which have one Drop down box contains two values 1. Professor, 2. Librarian. Now each values have different form fields. If I select Professor some different fields show be displayed and if I select Librarian some different fields display.

Can anybody tell me how I can do this??

```
<table width="435" border="0"> 
  <tr> <td>VIsit Date </td> <td><input type="text" name="textfield" /></td></tr> 
  <tr> <td>Last Visit Date </td> <td><input type="text" name="textfield2" /></td></tr> <tr> <td>Call Type </td> 
         <td>
           <select name="title" size="1"> 
             <option value ="Pro"> Professor </option>
             <option value ="Lib"> Librarian </option> </select>
         </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: <table width="435" border="0">

<tr>

<td>VIsit Date </td>

<td><input type="text" name="textfield" /></td>

</tr>

  

<tr>

<td>Last Visit Date </td>

<td><input type="text" name="textfield2" /></td>

</tr>

  

<tr>

<td>Call Type </td>

<td><select name="title" size="1">

<option value ="Pro"> Professor </option>

<option value ="Lib"> Librarian </option>

</select></td>

Comment: Are you bound to be using pure javascript and tables, or are you open to other solutions, like using jQuery and divs?

Comment: IF its in jquery ..this is a piece of cake! you use jquery ?

Comment: Yes I can use jquery..
But how can i do it in Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it in jquery, forget normal javascript.

JQUERY CODE (PUT THIS IN THE HEAD PART)

```
<script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js></script>
<script>
    $("#YOUR_SPECIFIC_ID").change(function(){
          if ($(this).val() == "Option2") {
                $('.option1form').hide('');
                $('.option2form').show('');
          }});
         </script>
         <script>
             $("#YOUR_SPECIFIC_ID").change(function(){
         if ($(this).val() == "Option1") {
                            $('.option1form').show('');
                $('.option2form').hide('');}});

</script>
```

Assign the select field an id:

```
<select name="asia" style="width:233px;" id="YOUR_SPECIFIC_ID">
    <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
    </select>
```

Then, you need to make the different forms for different selections.
like this.

```
<div class="option1form" style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="example1_1">
<input type="text" name="example1_2">
</div>

<div class="option2form" style="display:none">
<input type="text" name="example2_1">
<input type="text" name="example2_2">
</div>
```

Should work like this.

Comment: I tried the above code but its not running.. 

Only a drop box having option1 option2 is displaying but after selection nothing had happened??

Comment: Hmmm. I forgot a closing bracket but it still has some little error that needs to be fixed. I wrote that in a hurry and have lots of own code to focus on but I'll get it working.

Comment: Please let me know how to fix this??

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Page title</title>


   <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js></script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#callType").on('change', function(){
                $('.form1').toggle();
                $('.form2').toggle();
            });   
        });
   </script>
   <style>
       .form2 {
           display: none;
       }
   </style>

</head>
<body>

<select name="title" id="callType"> 
    <option value ="Pro"> Professor </option>
    <option value ="Lib"> Librarian </option> 
</select>

<div class="form1">
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="text1" />
    <input type="text" name="text2" value="text2" />
</div>

<div class="form2">
    <input type="text" name="text3" value="text3" />
    <input type="text" name="text4" value="text4" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you have just the two options in the dropdown, first form will be visible, and second will be hidden (display: none;). And on change, they will get their visibility toggled.

Few points forgot to mention: 
1. Have your event handler inside document ready. 
2. Keep in mind that in css 'visibility' and 'display' are different. Even if I said visibility, I was referring to display. jQuery show(), hide(), toggle() changes css display. The difference between "visibility: hidden" and "display: none" is that with visibility, invisible elements still take up space on the page.